# React: Passing props using rest spread operator to deep nested children

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to figure out a clean way to pass props down deeply nested children. But I am getting an error `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`. I am pretty sure it is something simple and stupid, but don't seem to be able to figure out. Here is my code:

```
class App2 extends React.Component {
  state= {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    prop3: 3
  }

  render () {
    return <ParentComponent {...this.state} />
  }
}



const ParentComponent = (props) => {
   <div>
     <h1>Parent Component</h1>
     <ChildComponent {...props} />
   </div>
};

const ChildComponent = ({prop1, ...rest}) =>{
  <div>
    <h1>Child Component with prop1={prop1}</h1>
    <GrandChildComponent {...rest} />
  </div>
};

const GrandChildComponent = ({prop2, prop3})=> {
  <div>
    <h1>Grand Child Component with prop2={prop2} and prop3={prop3}</h1>
  </div>
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, got it. Was using {} instead of ()
:)

```
class App2 extends React.Component {
  state= {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    prop3: 3
  }

  render () {
    return <ParentComponent {...this.state} />
  }
}



const ParentComponent = (props) => (
   <div>
     <h1>Parent Component</h1>
     <ChildComponent {...props} />
   </div>
);

const ChildComponent = ({prop1, ...rest}) =>(
  <div>
    <h1>Child Component with prop1={prop1}</h1>
    <GrandChildComponent {...rest} />
  </div>
);

const GrandChildComponent = ({prop2, prop3})=> (
  <div>
    <h1>Grand Child Component with prop2={prop2} and prop3={prop3}</h1>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Just close or delete your question. If it's just a typographical error then there is no point in leaving this open.

Comment: This pattern might be useful for somebody. I am leaving the question on, downvotes notwithstanding.